# HTML form submit giving 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, html, rest, post, exist-db

I'm submitting a HTML form to REST(eXist db) web service using POST method.A normal submission is giving **400 bad request**

Here is my HTML code

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     /* function createXMLHttpRequest()
       {
        if( typeof XMLHttpRequest == "undefined" )
        XMLHttpRequest = function() 
         {
          try 
          { 
           return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
          } 
         catch(e) {}
          try 
          { 
           return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
          } 
         catch(e) {}
          try
          { 
          return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") 
          } 
         catch(e) {}
          try 
          { 
          return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") 
          } 
         catch(e) {}
         throw new Error( "This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest." )
      };
       return new XMLHttpRequest();
     }

var AJAX = createXMLHttpRequest();*/
function submitForm()
 {

    //AJAX.open("POST",'http://localhost:8899/exist/rest/db/xql/sample.xq');
   // AJAX.send(document.form.xmlData.value);
   document.form.submit();
 };
</script>
<head>  
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <form name='form' action="http://localhost:8899/exist/rest/db/xql/sample.xq"  enctype="text/plain" method="post">
   <input type="text" name="xmlData"/>
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()";>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The commented code is to send POST request using AJAX.
I captured the http header request and response for form submit and AJAX submit
These are the request headers:

HTML form submit header:

```
(Request-Line)  POST /exist/rest/db/xql/sample.xq HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost:8899
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    text/plain
Content-Length  26
```

AJAX request header:

```
(Request-Line)  POST /exist/rest/db/xql/sample.xq HTTP/1.1
Host    localhost:8899
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  16
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Origin  null
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

Im not getting what's wrong in my code .
Im working on this for 2 days but i din't find any solution.
Please look into this and provide a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mavroscy you don't say! But the question here is what causes the error.

Comment: Please post a stripped-down version of your code to get proper responses. Plus, posting the server side code will help a lot.

Comment: Server side code was done by some other im also trying to receive the code

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because you're sending only the value in your data.

You need to send a name = value pair.

Comment: can u pls give me an example?

Comment: I can't really write actual code from the mobile browser I'm on, but look not only on the headers, but on the actual data too. There's a difference between your Ajax method and the browser native submission.

Comment: Also of anyone is willing to help and write some good example code I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sumbits data to the server as it should be. There must be some problem with your server side code.

Quoting from checkupdown.com  about error 400

400 errors in the HTTP cycle

1.Any client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) goes through the following cycle:

2.Obtain an IP address from the IP name of the site (the site URL without the leading 'http://'). This lookup (conversion of IP name to IP address) is provided by domain name servers (DNSs).

3.Open an IP socket connection to that IP address.

4.Write an HTTP data stream through that socket.

5.Receive an HTTP data stream back from the Web server in response. This data stream contains status codes whose values are determined by the HTTP protocol. Parse this data stream for status codes and other useful information.

**This error occurs in the final step above when the client receives an HTTP status code it recognises as '400'.**

Comment: I want to submit the form without AJAX.

Comment: i thought you wanted to submit an AJAX request. For using a simple post request your code looks fine to me. Better check your server side code

Comment: Most of the points are true, but they don't relate to the question here. Unless OP posts the server side language, we can't point out anything for sure.

Answer (score -1):

But you aren't sending any parameters with the Ajax POST?

The Ajax code should look something like this:

```
var xmlData=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("xmlData").value);
var parameters="xmlData="+xmlData;
AJAX.open("POST", "'http://localhost:8899/exist/rest/db/xql/sample.xq", true)
AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
AJAX.send(parameters)
```