# XMLHttpRequest Returning Bad Request (400) while calling from java script , if i am calling from Java or Postman client it working fine

Tags: javascript, java, spring, rest, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to call Spring rest method using java script. 
I am getting:

**POST http://www.davco.com/search/loginAuthentication 400 (Bad Request)**

Below is my Java scrpt Code to invoke Spring REST service that I have

```
   var userEmailId= $("#emailAddress").val();
   var userPwd= $("#userPassword").val();

    if (empty(userPwd)) {
        alert("Please enter password");
        return false;
    }

    var http = new createXMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "/search/loginAuthentication";
    var params = 'eid=' +userEmailId+'&amp;pwd='+userPwd

    http.open("POST", url, true);
    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/xml");
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 &amp;&amp; http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);
```

[image]
When i am trying to call same method from Google Postman client I am able to hit services and get the response..

I am not able to understand what wrong i am doing while  i am calling it form Javascrpt. I have refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810492/html-form-submit-giving-400-bad-request), this [link as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773725/getting-400-bad-request-when-using-multipart-form-data-as-content-type-in-xhr).

I tried different **Content-type** header like :

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "Accept=application/xml");

I am seeing from browser request and request payload for POST call is going like below that is correct :

[image]

**Below is my Spring Rest Services Code:**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/loginAuthentication" ,headers = "Accept=application/xml, application/json, text/html")
    public @ResponseBody String loginAuthnticationForHTEtb(@RequestParam("eid") String userEmailId,@RequestParam("pwd") String password
            ,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {   

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        try {
            String domainVraiable=Context.getDomainName();
            int inxexOfDot=domainVraiable.indexOf(".")+1;
            int lastIndexOf=domainVraiable.lastIndexOf(".");

            ....
```

I am just wondering why it working and i am able to call from PostMan Client but not working while i am trying  to call from java script? As you can see in below screenshot.

[image]

Thanks in advance for any kind of clue or information to get rid of this. I spend almost a day but could not figured out.

Comment: `var params = 'eid=' +userEmailId+'&amp;pwd='+userPwd` - try changing that to `var params = 'eid=' +userEmailId+'&pwd='+userPwd`

Comment: I am trying this code in JSPX page so i need to escape XML Character. when parser and  displayed in browser windows it shows like this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/1obo5.jpg

that &amp; is not and issue after JSP translation it will convert to & only.  what you can see .

I have attached image of Code after parse and display in browser window. I tried so many things with in this but could not figure out what other things i am missing.

Comment: check the request parameters in the browser developer tools network tab for that request, make sure it looks right there

Comment: Yes request  payload is going correct way i have added images of chrome network tab from developer tools : http://i.stack.imgur.com/bxcur.jpg

Comment: Apparently this is not a REST service, since it violates the stateless constraint.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
var params = {
   eid:userEmailId,
   pwd:userPwd
};

http.send(params);
```

or:

```
 var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("eid", userEmailId);
    formData.append("pwd", userPwd);

    http.send(formData);
```

Comment: I tried both way to setting the parameter but same issue i am getting some problem 400 bad request. 
I am thinking that its not problem with sending parameter. i think some service or they way i am trying to call is problem but not understanding what mistake i am doing.

Comment: You tried with: http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");   ?

Comment: I had tried all possible header including that one which you have mention above. But could not work. So i am able to work like this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/39723936/582421

Same i have posted as above. 
Thanks for your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time,still I am not able to figure out what exactly the problem in above implementation.

But now I change like this and working fine with below style :

```
var response = $.post("/search/loginAuthentication",{"eid":userEmailId, "pwd" :userPwd},
        function(data,status){
                processAuthenticationResponse(data);    
        },'json');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. But then I sent string of JSON instead of JSON object. Then it worked.

```
request.send(JSON.stringify(json));
```